# Android ConstraintLayout width wasn't correct when I set the activity attribute "android:windowIsFloating" as true

Tags: android

It doesn't correctly measure the width when I use '0dp' which named Match Constraints.It only measure the first TextView's width.

My activity's style:

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle2"  parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>　　　　　　　　
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

My layou:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingBottom="18dp">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="@string/search_condition_title"
    android:textColor="@color/font_color"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchDispatchStartTimeTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/search_condition_dispatch_time"
    android:textColor="@color/font_color"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchTitle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resetStartTime"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25px"
    android:background="@mipmap/reset"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/searchDispatchStartTimeTitle" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchDispatchStartTime"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textarea_shape"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="@string/search_condition_dispatch_time_hint"
    android:textColor="@color/font_color"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/resetStartTime"        
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/searchDispatchStartTimeTitle" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want to accomplish is making a dialog to show some input controls, but current project's dialogs are implement by activities which has an  "android:windowIsFloating" attribute with a value of true.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your style, Add attribute for dialog aspect size and `windowFullScreen`

**EXAMPLE**

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle2" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">85%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">85%</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    .....
</style>
```

**or**

There is also a programmatic way to modify the attributes of a window's size.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = (int) (display.getWidth() * 0.7); 
int height = (int) (display.getHeight() * 0.9);  
getWindow().getAttributes().width = width;
getWindow().getAttributes().height = height;
```

Comment: @Beetlebum233 i'm glad to help you